# Tool to send request and receive response

Tags: html, browser, http-request

I am trying to inspect some html, which is not displayed correctly in IE. when I look at the html in IE and FF, they are both different slightly and this might be causing the issue.

I want to grab html returned from the server and thus do not want to send request using a browser.
can anyone advise me any such tool ??

Comment: Are you looking at the HTML source (with View Source) or the generated DOM (with debug tools)? The source should be the same in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using linux or unix system, you can use `curl` to do that.

to send GET request:

```
curl "<< request-url >>"
```

to send POST request:

```
curl --data "<< post-parameter >>" "<< request-url >>"
```

And you can use -X option to define what HTTP method you want to send with.

or maybe you're using Windows, you can use the web tool to send GET/POST requests like

http://hurl.it/

Answer (score 0):

`curl` would do the trick. `curl http://www.google.com`, for example.